# Should the return value of every function be checked?

Tags: c, winapi

I have seen code like this

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
TextOut(hdc, x, y, L"Hello", 5);
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

What if `BeginPaint()` fails? Should the return value of every function called be checked in important apps like for example commercial apps?

Comment: Yes!!! Because they are "important" apps..

Comment: I can't tell if you're joking or not, but checking every return value makes the code more complex

Comment: Well, I don't know what your code does, but I have been working with Android, and doing some network related stuff, and I have been trying to possibly cover all my areas, its always better to complicate your code than to have a crash on the user device, that what I believe!

Comment: No, you don't have to check everything. You should check some functions, for example when creating a new file, lots of things can go wrong and the function can easily fail. But other functions like `BeginPaint` do not fail unless there is a serious problem with OS, in which case everything else is failing anyway. There is no simple answer, it goes case by case.

Comment: You should never check for an error you're not prepared to handle.

Comment: What should you do if BeginPaint fails?

Comment: Also, most Win32 functions will "silently" ignore invalid arguments (they'll fail themselves, and set an error code, but not crash). That means if BeginPaint fails in this code, TextOut will fail, and EndPaint will fail because BeginPaint wasn't called. End result: "Hello" is not displayed, but no crash.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I came across a `printf()` that had it's return value used much less checked.

Comment: Its a good practice to check return type of a function, specially for *more impact functions*, or you might end up with an abnormal behavior by the program when the function fails or mostly when the function reads *bad input* from a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeginPaint` function can fail, in which case `hdc` will be set to `NULL`.  The Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't specify what happens when a `NULL` `hdc` is passed to `TextOut`, but it won't be something good.  Thus checking the return value of `BeginPaint` is needed if the code is to be considered reliable.

When in doubt, you should check the return value of functions.  I've seen way too much code that assumes that memory allocation always succeeds, file systems don't fill up, and networking functions always succeed.

Comment: Except ... what will you *do* if you detect that BeginPaint has failed?  Will it really be a significant improvement over allowing the code to crash, or to fail silently, whichever is applicable?  Is it worth it, when there are no known circumstances under which such a failure will occur?  (File operations and network operations are different, because we *do* know that they might fail.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston- If BeginPaint fails, at the very least the program should log the failure before cleaning up and exiting.  Failing silently is really bad, because it is really hard to track down what failed.  Crashing is ok for development code, but not for production.  And where does Microsoft say that BeginPaint won't fail?  Not anyplace I saw.

Comment: Oh, there's a colourable case for adding logging code to everything "just in case".  But IMO there comes a point where it is more likely to introduce problems than to resolve them.  You can't prevent crashes - in the code fragment in the question, the process *will* crash if `ps` is null, so is there really a significant benefit to preventing the process from crashing if `hwnd` is null?  (OTOH, it might be nice to have a language feature for this - syntactic sugar that logs and exits without obscuring the intent of the code.  Like exceptions, only less horrible.)

Comment: And of course MS don't say BeginPaint won't fail, because it will - if you've used it improperly (in which case you should notice that your code doesn't work) or if something in the OS state is seriously weird (in which case logging the error won't help).

Comment: I think your own words say it quite well, actually: "when in doubt".  Unless you're a complete novice at Windows GUI code, you're not going to be in doubt about the success of BeginPaint.